# WooCommerce variable products: keep only "min" price with a custom label

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

In the functions file I have added a filter hook to add a custom label before the variation product "min" price.

How can I get the label in the same line as the price?

See my code and the screenshot below:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_sale_price_html', 'wc_wc20_variation_price_format', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'wc_wc20_variation_price_format', 10, 2 );
function wc_wc20_variation_price_format( $price, $product ) {
    $min_price = $product->get_variation_price( 'min', true );
    $price = sprintf( __( 'From%1$s', 'woocommerce' ), wc_price( $min_price ) );
    return $price;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since WooCommerce 3, **`woocommerce_variable_sale_price_html`** hook is deprecated and not anymore useful. If you don't care about "min" sale price *(when the min price is on sale)*, you can use this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'custom_min_max_variable_price_html', 10, 2 );
function custom_min_max_variable_price_html( $price, $product ) {
    $prices = $product->get_variation_prices( true );
    $min_price = current( $prices['price'] );

    $min_price_html = wc_price( $min_price ) . $product->get_price_suffix();
    $price = sprintf( __( 'From %1$s', 'woocommerce' ), $min_price_html );

    return $price;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested and works on WooCommerce 3+. You will get something like this:

[image]

If you care about "min" sale price *(when the min price is on sale)*, and you want to display both prices, you should use this code instead:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'custom_min_max_variable_price_html', 10, 2 );
function custom_min_max_variable_price_html( $price, $product ) {
    $prices = $product->get_variation_prices( true );
    $min_price = current( $prices['price'] );

    $min_keys = current(array_keys( $prices['price'] ));
    $min_price_regular = $prices['regular_price'][$min_keys];
    $min_price_html = wc_price( $min_price ) . $product->get_price_suffix();

    if( $min_price_regular != $min_price ){ // When min price is on sale (Can be removed)
        $min_price_regular_html = '<del>' . wc_price( $min_price_regular ) . $product->get_price_suffix() . '</del>';
        $min_price_html = $min_price_regular_html .'<ins>' . $min_price_html . '</ins>';
    }
    $price = sprintf( __( 'From %1$s', 'woocommerce' ), $min_price_html );

    return $price;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested and works on WooCommerce 3+. You will get something like this:

[image]

> To handle when all variations prices are the same:
>
> [WooCommerce variable products: Display the min price with a custom text for different prices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56935990/woocommerce-variable-products-display-the-min-price-with-a-custom-text-for-diff/57059722#57059722)