# WooCommerce variable products: Display the min price with a custom text for different prices

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, price

I'm setting up a function for Woocommerce that display discount price and the regular price for variable product, this function add a " from to " text before the price range.

The *"[WooCommerce variable products: keep only "min" price with a custom label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46005952/woocommerce-variable-products-keep-only-min-price-with-a-custom-label/46009513#46009513)"* answer thread matches the best with what I am looking for and work like a charm!

But when all variations in a variable product have the same prices, the " start from " should not be displayed.

So I've made a simple try and add below the "if" condition

```
else {
    $price = sprintf( __( '%1$s', 'woocommerce' ), $min_price_html );
return $price;
}
```

and integrate in the if condition:

```
$price = sprintf( __( 'À partir de %1$s', 'woocommerce' ), $min_price_html );
    return $price;
```

But it doesn't really work. Some help is appreciated and welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To handle when all variations of a variable product are the same, you need to use [`array_unique()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) php function and `count()` to look if all variation prices are the same.

So the code will be slightly different:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'custom_min_max_variable_price_html', 10, 2 );
function custom_min_max_variable_price_html( $price, $product ) {
    $prices = $product->get_variation_prices( true );
    $count  = (int) count( array_unique( $prices['price'] ));

    // When all variations prices are the same
    if( $count === 1 )
        return $price;

    $min_price = current( $prices['price'] );
    $min_keys  = current(array_keys( $prices['price'] ));

    $min_reg_price  = $prices['regular_price'][$min_keys];
    $min_price_html = wc_price( $min_price ) . $product->get_price_suffix();

    // When min price is on sale (Can be removed)
    if( $min_reg_price != $min_price ) {
        $min_price_reg_html = '<del>' . wc_price( $min_reg_price ) . $product->get_price_suffix() . '</del>';
        $min_price_html = $min_price_reg_html .'<ins>' . $min_price_html . '</ins>';
    }
    $price = sprintf( __( 'À partir de %s', 'woocommerce' ), $min_price_html );

    return $price;
}
```

*Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Comment: Thx you so much Loic, the function work greatly! And if i want to have the regular price and the sales price like the second "**if**" of the function but without the " à partir de " too, it's possible ?