# Get minimum price for simple and variable products in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

I need to show a list of simple and variable products with their prices displayed as "From $XX". But I've seen some methods like below.

```
$min_price  = $product->get_variation_price( 'min', true ); //I guess this only works for variable products
$min_price = $product->get_price_html(); //Will this guarantee to show the priceof the cheapest variation in a variable product?
$min_price = $product->get_price(); //How about this?
```

So, which is the best way to ensure I always get the lowest price for products regardless of them being simple or variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The **minimum price** is exclusively for variable products (price range)

For variable products only to get the min active price amount (non formatted) you will use:

```
$min_price = $product->get_variation_price( 'min' );
$min_price_for display = $product->get_variation_price( 'min', true ); // for display
```

For other product types (including variations) to get the active price amount (non formatted) you will use:

```
$price = $product->get_price();
```

For all products to get the *formatted* displayed price, you will use:

```
$formatted_price = $product->get_price_html();
```

This last one can give a price range for variable products and for products on sale.

---

Related: [WooCommerce variable products: keep only "min" price with a custom label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46005952/woocommerce-variable-products-keep-only-min-price-with-a-custom-label/46009513#46009513)

Comment: You're the man! I've learned so much from all your answers on StackOverflow. But may I ask, what do you mean by ACTIVE price under "$price = $product->get_price();" Do you mean the price that are enabled/visible/set in each variation or simple product or a price of one product that has been actively purchased (like most people purchase a product variation at a specific price)

Comment: @worisi24 If product is on sale, the active price is the sale price, if not it is the regular price *(because you can also use the `WC_Product` methods `get_sale_price()` or `get_regular_price()`)*.